# Video autoplay still occurring even though all autoplay settings are off (Firefox Normandy)

Tags: firefox

I am using Firefox 66.0.3, turned off autoplay settings, but I am still getting autoplaying news pages like the following:

https://www.ksdk.com/article/news/investigations/teacher-charged-with-hiring-hitman-to-kill-student-after-molestation-accusation-pleads-not-guilty/63-c5eeab38-7825-41b7-b969-2907ab1d1f1f

How can I stop autoplay? Here are my settings:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I stop autoplay?

You need to set `media.autoplay.default` to `1`, as [0=Allowed, 1=Blocked, 2=Prompt] and `media.autoplay.enabled.user-gestures-needed` to `false`.

Sources [Just got upgrade to ver 66, Autoplay still not disabled](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1253589) and [Settings don't exist in FF 64 for "Allow or block media autoplay in Firefox"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1253589)